# tooltip won't work; div won't display

Tags: javascript, tooltip

I'm very new to JavaScript, and I'm practicing making a tooltip. I get the text, of course, but can't style it with what's in my CSS.

I've been through so many tutorials and q&a's trying to find the answer, and I'm still confused.

Is there anything that stands out in my code that is getting in my way?

Here is my code:

```
<head>
<style>
body {
background-color: gray;
}

.tooltip {
    background:blue;
    font-size:60px;
    height:70px;
    width:160px;
    padding:25px;
    color:black;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="demo">
<img src = "pic1.jpg" title="The tooltip text #1" />
</div>


<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" 
    src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" 
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{

$("#demo img[title]").tooltip();

});
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: 1. You are loading two different versions of JQuery. 2. You aren't loading which ever tooltip plugin you think you are using

Comment: 2. But not jQuery UI, which has the tooltip functionality

Comment: 3. I don't see a tooltip library anywhere. That "title" tag shows a browser tooltip.

Comment: Oh! I must have left one from another tutorial in by accident. I'll fix these things, this is perfect! Thank you!